# SAS Unable to access blobs storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics

I have a stream analytics job take its input from blob storage, I get it to work fine from 11AM to 1AM next day- UTC+2:00 local time-, other than that, its down, no input to SAS no output, I believe that the problem at blob storage, I see new blobs keep created after 1AM, so there're many blobs but SAS unable to process these blobs after 1AM until 11AM, why?
When I sample input data at SAS during 11AM to 1AM, I get successful sampled data, but if I do the sampling after 1AM until 11AM, I got no valid samples available error message, why?
Why are the blobs available during this period and no elsewhere?

Comment: Could you share your sas URI start time and expiry time?

Comment: Ayman, if you schedule a copy or get outside of that specific window, without using the stream analytics job, are you successful on this task ? Can you also include any logs during or/and after the job is processed ?

Comment: Hi, Is your blob input partitioned by time?  If so, in your blob storage, did you set the hour "folder" as 01, 02, 03, etc. for the single digit hours?